# Case-insensitive search with "/" and "-"

Tags: elasticsearch

This question is a combination of two my questions:

- [Match by substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400872/match-by-substring)
- [Set normalizer for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518837/set-normalizer-for-field)

Answer in the first question allow me to search data with "/" and "-". But search is case-sensitive.

In second question I have case-insensitive search, but searching "/" and "-" is broken.

What I have now:

```
{  
    "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "lowerasciinormalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
             "entity": {
                 "properties": {

                     "Description": {
              "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "whitespace",
                          "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                  "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"      
                                }
                            }
              },

                    "Name": {
              "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "whitespace",
                    "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                  "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"      
                                }
                            }
            }
            }
     }
    }
}
```

This index allow me to do case-insensitive search, but I can not find documents like this:

```
PUT
{
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "author": "Some 28/56 another"
}

POST
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { "default_field": "author", "query": "*28\\/56*" }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have case-insensitive search which will work with "/" and "-" ?

Comment: I don't see `author` under `properties` in your mapping. What is its data type and if it is text what analyzer have you specified for this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined an analyzer named `folding` which can fulfil your requirement of case-insensitive search with `/` and `-` not being used to tokenize the input string. You should add `author` in the mapping as below:

```
"author": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "folding"
}
```

Then use the query below for a match:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "author",
      "query": "28\\/859"
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want lowercase with whitespace tokenizer then define another analyzer as below:

```
"lowercaseWs": {
  "filter": [
    "lowercase"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "whitespace"
}
```

Then use the above with `author` field as below:

```
"author": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "lowercaseWs"
}
```